# How to use checkmark for UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios9

I am trying to create a simple todo list app for learning purposes i. I want to be able to click on a row and add a check mark and when clicked again i want it to go away. i have looked at several other examples but nothing is working. How can i achieve this?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,         UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tbView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tbView.reloadData()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tbView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return tasks.manager.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Tasks")

    //Assign the contents of our var "items" to the textLabel of each cell
    cell.textLabel!.text = tasks.manager[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = tasks.manager[indexPath.row].time

    return cell

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

        tasks.manager.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tbView.reloadData()
    }
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: You need to also update your data model i.e. isSelected, as when you scroll those checkmarks will vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply, you can use this code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if (cell!.accessoryType == .Checkmark) {
        cell!.accessoryType = .None
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This way, when you re-select cell, the checkmark will adjust accordingly.

However, you shouldn't modify cell checkmark this way as the cell will get re used when you scroll.
You need to update your data model instead it above approach.

so in your data model, add new property to hold checkmark state and then use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Tasks")

    //Assign the contents of our var "items" to the textLabel of each cell
    cell.textLabel!.text = tasks.manager[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = tasks.manager[indexPath.row].time

    if tasks.manager[indexPath.row].isSelected { //assume that isSelected is bool
        cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = .None
    }

    return cell
}
```

and then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` update the model.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let dataModel = tasks.manager[indexPath.row]
    dataModel.isSelected = !dataModel.isSelected
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: The first block of code in this answer is not how it should be done. In fact, it doesn't even work. The 2nd half is better. But the 2nd `didSelectRowAt` should not reload the whole table view. Juts reload the one row at `indexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using a table view in a storyboard. If that's the case, in the attributes inspector, you can choose a chick mark as the style.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need both `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` methods of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

You can simple use them like this!

Deselect

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .None
    //tableView.reloadData()
}`

Select

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    //tableView.reloadData()
}`